# SE is missing from list of stored passwords

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I went to `settings -> advanced -> manage passwords` and I'm seeing a list of websites that Chrome has saved passwords for, and I'm not seeing Stack Exchange. Obviously Chrome is storing it; I don't have to re-enter my password when I reboot. Why isn't it showing up?

Comment: Do you happen to have a plugin that remembers passwords?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Check for `stackauth.com`

Comment: @Sathya you mean in thee ;list of sites with stored websites? It's not there.

Answer (score 2):

If you logged in using a Google OpenID then "Google" will be where your login password is saved for these sites.

Go to your account preferences for a Stack Exchange site and look at the "My Logins" page. You can get there by clicking on your user profile at the top of the page, clicking `Edit Profile & Settings` and then looking for `My Logins` about halfway down the list on the left hand side. That should take you to your logins page: `https://superuser.com/users/mylogins/<your user id number>/`

If you only see Google there then you are using their OpenID system to provide you a login.

[What is OpenID?](http://openid.net/what-is-openid/):

> With OpenID, your password is only given to your identity provider, and that provider then confirms your identity to the websites you visit.  Other than your provider, **no website ever sees your password,** so you don’t need to worry about an unscrupulous or insecure website compromising your identity.